# How to make renderer setStyle method work

Tags: angular

I'm working on angular java using Visual Code as Editor. I'm facing an issue while using the renderer setStyle property.

Can anyone tell me the solution ?

Here is the code:

```
import { Directive, Renderer2, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';


export class BetterHighlightDirective implements OnInit
{
  
   constructor(private elRef: ElementRef ,private renderer: Renderer2)
   { }
  
    ngOnInit()

       {
          this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement,'color','yellow');
       }
}
```

Here the yellow color is not showing up on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nayana welcome to SO,
try to implement your code in a directive instead of the component. Something like:

**// Directive**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[betterHighlight]',
})
export class BetterHighlightDirective {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'color', 'yellow');
  }
}
```

**// HTML template**

```
<div betterHighlight>
  Highlight this better
</div>
```

Do not forget to add it into your module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ... ],
  declarations: [ ..., BetterHighlightDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ ... ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```